# About the Definition of a Sobolev Space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have a question about the usual definition of a Sobolev spaces.

Especially, let $f \in W^{1,2} (\Bbb R^n)$. I have thought that this notation means that $$  \int_{\Bbb R^n} |f|^2 + | \partial_1 f|^2 + \cdots + | \partial_n f|^2 < \infty $$ where $\partial_i$ means that $i$th weak partial derivative. But I am wondering that this notation may include the product of derivatives, that is, $$  \int_{\Bbb R^n} |f|^2 + | \partial_1 f|^2 + \cdots + |\partial_n f |^2 + |\partial_1 f | | \partial_2 f | + \cdots + | \partial_{n-1} f | | \partial_n f| < \infty.$$

Which one is true in general?

Comment: In your last formula I don't see mixed derivatives, but just products of derivatives of order $1$ (using $2|ab|\leq a^2+b^2$ we can see they are equivalent).

Comment: @DavideGiraudo  Really thank you! you are right, they are not mixed derivatives. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$\begin{aligned} \int |\partial_1f|^2 + \cdots + |\partial_n f|^2 & \leq \int |\partial_1 f|^2 + \cdots + |\partial_n f|^2 + |\partial_1 f \partial_2 f| + \cdots + |\partial_{n-1} f \partial_n f| \\
&\leq \frac{n+1}{2}  \int |\partial_1 f|^2 + \cdots + \partial_n f|^2
\end{aligned} $$

By the arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean inequality
$$ |ab| \leq \frac{|a| + |b|}{2} $$
applied to the ${n \choose 2}$ "cross terms". So the two definitions are equivalent.